# How to call the variable defined inside withClockAndReset

Tags: chisel

I am using multiple clock in chisel.

In chisel3, I write following codes.

```
withClockAndReset(A_clk, A_rst) {
    val data_a = RegInit(0.U(4.W))
}
withClockAndReset(B_clk, B_rst) {
    val data_b = RegInit(0.U(4.W))
}
data_b := data_a
data_a := io.data
```

The compiler reported that the variable data_a could not be found.
The variable data_a is defined inside withClockAndReset, and I can't use this variable outside.

What can I do?

Comment: A_clk, B_clk, A_rst and B_rst is ok. The variable data_a which defined inside the withClockAndReset is not found, when I try to use it outside withClockAndReset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```scala
val data_a = withClockAndReset(A_clk, A_rst) {
    RegInit(0.U(4.W))
}
```

The issue is that you're defining a `val` in a separate scope.

Whatever the second argument list of `withClockAndReset` (what is put in the `{ \* ... *\ }`) returns. So, you can use this to return the register, module, etc. that you construct in the other clock/reset scope.